# How can I remove the BOM from XmlTextWriter using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, byte-order-mark, xmlwriter

How do remove the BOM from an XML file that is being created?

I have tried using the new UTF8Encoding(false) method, but it doesn't work. Here is the code I have:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(filename, new UTF8Encoding(false));
xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'");
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("items");
xmlWriter.Close();
xmlDoc.Load(filename);
XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
XmlElement item = xmlDoc.CreateElement("item");
root.AppendChild(item);
XmlElement itemCategory = xmlDoc.CreateElement("category");
XmlText itemCategoryText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("test");
item.AppendChild(itemCategory);
itemCategory.AppendChild(itemCategoryText);
xmlDoc.Save(filename);
```

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're saving the file twice - once with `XmlTextWriter` and once with `xmlDoc.Save`. Saving from the `XmlTextWriter` *isn't* adding a BOM - saving with `xmlDoc.Save` is.

Just save to a `TextWriter` instead, so that you can specify the encoding again:

```
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, false,
                                            new UTF8Encoding(false))
{
    xmlDoc.Save(writer);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the quick reply, so are you saying to remove the XmlTextWriter section at the beginning and only use the TextWriter at the end of the method?

Comment: Well it's not clear what your code is meant to be doing. Why are you currently saving the file and then reloading it?

Comment: Im just trying to create an XML file with a range of different nodes inside it. To be honest i was in a rush and pulled the section from another site and changed it where appropriate.

Comment: @Chris: Okay, in that case yes, you can move the XmlTextWriter part to the bottom - or just use `XmlDocument.Save` in the way I've shown in the answer.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your help, i finally managed to get this working.

Comment: I'm not sure why but this does not work for me the second parameter of StreamWriter must be a bool.

Comment: @rekire: Well you haven't told us *anything* about your context, which makes it hard to help you. What sort of app are you writing?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm implementing a console project (targeting .net 4.5). I Could fix this problem by using this constructor: `new StreamWriter(outfile, false, new UTF8Encoding(false))`. It's just wired that a constructor seems to been removed.

Comment: @rekire: I think it was my mistake, actually - it looks like there's a *stream* version with just an encoding, but not a *string* version. Will edit the answer.