# Getting "ï»¿" at the beginning of my XML File after save()

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, .net-4.0

I'm opening an existing XML file with C#, and I replace some nodes in there. All works fine. Just after I save it, I get the following characters at the beginning of the file:

```
ï»¿  (EF BB BF in HEX)
```

The whole first line:

```
 ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

The rest of the file looks like a normal XML file.
The simplified code is here:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlSourceFile);
XmlNode translation = doc.SelectSingleNode("//trans-unit[@id='127']");
translation.InnerText = "testing";
doc.Save(xmlTranslatedFile);
```

I'm using a C# [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application with .NET 4.0.

Any ideas? Why would it do that? Can we disable that somehow? It's for Adobe InCopy, and it does not open it like this.

**UPDATE**:
Alternative Solution:

Saving it with the XmlTextWriter works too:

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(inCopyFilename, null);
doc.Save(writer);
```

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755958/how-can-i-remove-bom-from-xmltextwriter-using-c) here - Jon Skeet explains how to use remove the BOM when saving your XMLDocument, if that is what you need.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is the [UTF-8 BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html), which is actually discouraged by the Unicode standard:

> http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.0.0/ch02.pdf
>
> Use of a BOM is neither required nor
>   recommended for UTF-8, but may be
>   encountered in contexts where UTF-8
>   data is converted from other encoding
>   forms that use a BOM or where the BOM
>   is used as a UTF-8 signature

You may disable it using:

```
var sw = new IO.StreamWriter(path, new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false));
doc.Save(sw);
sw.Close();
```

Comment: Huh, I never knew it was discouraged... if it is, then how are programs supposed to detect encodings?

Comment: @Lambert: XML either specifies an encoding in the header or (missing that) is UTF-8 by default.

Comment: @Lambert: *for UTF-8* is the key part of the phrase.  If you *know* it is utf-8 then there's no point, no endian-ness trouble.  The odds of reading an xml file encoded in utf-16be without a bom are still zilch, even if it is declared in the processing instruction.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. That helped. I've updated the question with another solution that I found after your input.

Comment: This code does not compile.  The first argument to `StreamWriter` is a `Stream`, not a path.  Also, `sw` will never be closed if `doc.Save(sw);` throws an Exception.  Classic case for the `using` statement.

Comment: @EricJ. You are correct, this is a classic case for the `using` statement. It seems like MS has updated the documentation for `StreamWriter(String)` constructor, which now implicitly "creates a StreamWriter with UTF-8 encoding without a Byte-Order Mark (BOM)". MS also have updated the documentation for .NET 2.0 to say the same thing. So, unless MS made a mistake, the `StreamWriter(String)` constructor should suffice.

Answer (score 6):

It's a UTF-8 [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) and is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the encoding of the XmlDocument. Below is the example copied from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldeclaration.encoding.aspx)

```
using System; using System.IO; using System.Xml;

public class Sample {

  public static void Main() {

    // Create and load the XML document.
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string xmlString = "<book><title>Oberon's Legacy</title></book>";
    doc.Load(new StringReader(xmlString));

    // Create an XML declaration. 
    XmlDeclaration xmldecl;
    xmldecl = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0",null,null);
    xmldecl.Encoding="UTF-16";
    xmldecl.Standalone="yes";     

    // Add the new node to the document.
    XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
    doc.InsertBefore(xmldecl, root);

    // Display the modified XML document 
    Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);

  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As everybody else mentioned, it's Unicode issue.

I advise you to try [LINQ To XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). Although not really related, I mention it as it's super easy compared to old ways and, more importantly, I assume it might have automatic resolutions to issues like these without extra coding from you.