# actionscript 3.0 XML file saves with a couple random characters in the beginning of the file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I am using [this adobe example](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ByteArrays_2.html)  under "reading and writing objects" to try and convert an XML file to a byteArray and save the file somewhere. I use [this](https://github.com/gabriel/as3httpclient) to upload the file to s3. When i download the XML file with s3 i get 4 random characters in front of the XML file. Looking into the issue [[example of what i think is happening]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614378/getting-i-at-the-beginning-of-my-xml-file-after-save), it seems that the extra characters are being created with the encoding scheme. However, adobes example uses writeObject to convert an XML to a byteArray, so I don't see how i am using the incorrect encoding scheme.

my code is fairly simple.

creating the byteArray:

```
            var _bookXml:XML = _book.serialize(); //converts book to XML
                var photobookXmlName:String = photobookToken + "_layout.xml";
                _s3uploader.uploadObjectToS3(_bookXml, photobookXmlName); //uploads XML
```

and the uploadObjectToS3 code:

```
    public function uploadObjectToS3(file:Object, objectName:String):void{
        var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
        data.writeObject(file);
        data.position = 0;
        //code to do s3 upload
    }
```

heres a before/after example XML file i used as a test case:

before:

```
<xml>
  <test>data</test>
</xml>
```

after:

```
��5<xml>
  <test>data</test>
</xml>
```

any idea how to fix this issue so I dont get random characters? I've tried a few things but they didn't work.

thanks

edit: before anyone suggests, i already trtied changing the uploadObjectToS3 input form an object to a ByteArray. It didnt change anything.

Comment: the other question you referenced is referring to byte order marks. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark for more details. but that's not what you are seeing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `data.writeObject(file);`. Those are *not* random characters, those are serialization markers.

You aren't sending an xml document to S3, you are sending a *serialized* Actionscript `XML` object (in AMF3 format).

`_bookXml.toXMLString()` will give you the xml document as a string. then you should be able to use `ByteArray.writeMultiByte()` to get what you want. Check out the following example:

```js
    var test:XML = <test><data>Data</data></test>;

    var serializeObject:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    serializeObject.writeObject(test);
    trace(serializeObject.toString());

    var rawString:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    rawString.writeMultiByte(test.toXMLString(), 'utf-8');
    trace(rawString.toString());
```

The output is:

```
�E<test>
  <data>Data</data>
</test>

<test>
  <data>Data</data>
</test>
```

The difference is the first is a serialized object (that you could use `.readObject()` to deserialize the object out of the byte array back into a `XML` object in flash). The latter is simply the raw bytes of the string (in utf-8).

In your case, I would suggest something like this:

```js
public function uploadObjectToS3(file:Object, objectName:String):void{
    var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
    data.writeObject(file);
    data.position = 0;

    uploadByteArrayToS3(data, objectName);
}

public function uploadXmlToS3(file:XML, objectName:String):void{
    var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
    data.writeMultiByte(file.toXMLString(), "utf-8");
    data.position = 0;

    uploadByteArrayToS3(data, objectName);
}

private function uploadByteArrayToS3(file:ByteArray, objectName:String):void{
    //code to do s3 upload
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are receiving a unicode prefix per line, I believe you are seeing the length of the string for deserialization.

This would be exhibited by:

writeUTF(value:String) - Writes a UTF-8 string to the file stream, byte stream, or byte array. The length of the UTF-8 string in bytes is written first, as a 16-bit integer, followed by the bytes representing the characters of the string.

writeUTFBytes(value:String) - Writes a UTF-8 string. Similar to writeUTF(), but does not prefix the string with a 16-bit length word.