# Make Eclipse recognize unknown file extension as xml

Tags: eclipse

I have an xml file but the extension is ".agen". Is there a way to make Eclipse recognize the file extension and display the content as xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window->Preferences->General->Editor->File Associations

Comment: A very strange thing happens when I do that. After adding the file extension and I open the file, the first line of the file shows ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>. If I rename the file to .xml and open it, those first 3 characters are gone. Any reason why? It's as though it can't read the correct encoding.

Comment: Seems, your file contains BOM for recogneze UTF-8 encoding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614378/getting-ï-at-the-beginning-of-my-xml-file-after-save.  If you associate xml-editor for extensions .agen then this 3 charactes will go.

Comment: OK, but why does it open correctly just by adding the .xml extension?