# how eclipse recognize *.xml.vm as xml extension?

Tags: xml, eclipse

Difference this

[Make Eclipse recognize unknown file extension as xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24624489)

I have velocity files based on XML, I want open them as XML file. In

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editor -> File Associations
```

I cannot add `*.xml.vm` to file types tab, how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.xml.vm` isn't a valid filename extension. `.vm` would be. And use the `Content Types` preference page, not `File Associations`, as the [FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_use_my_own_filename_extensions_in_the_XML_editor.3F_It_only_works_correctly_if_a_file_ends_with_.xml.) says.