# How to avoid writing a BOM when saving an XmlDocument to a file?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, byte-order-mark

I read XML from WCF and I need to save the XML to my disk but I get a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character when I save it.  I don't want this character included, so I tried different ways to write the document without it, but it is not working, I don't know what is wrong.  Any idea?

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

xmlDoc.LoadXml(vReply.xmlDocumento);

////-------------------------- Save without BOM ï»¿ -----------------------

var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(vReply.xmlDocumento);
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false); // The false means, do not emit the BOM.
using (XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create("c://temp/my.xml", settings))
{
    xmlDoc.Save(w);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the BOM from XmlTextWriter using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755958/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-xmltextwriter-using-c)

Comment: wcf is using http so you need to convert any http special character to/from their http values using System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) and System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string).  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/4VzxJd.  The bytes written to the file do not contain a BOM, they correctly start with the bytes `60,63,120,109,108,32,118,101,114,115,105,111,110,61,34,49,46,48,34,32,101,110,99,111,100,105,110,103,61,34,117,116,102,45,56,34,63,62` which correspond to the XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.  Notice no BOM is included.  Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?

Comment: (Of course the bytes in the `MemoryStream stream` might contain a BOM since you did not write them using `UTF8Encoding(false)`.  Only the file `"c://temp/my.xml"` should be written without the BOM.)

Comment: This is the example of code code that i wanto to revove

Comment: This is the example of bom code that i wanto to remove       o;?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: @KlingCan that's not a BOM; that's xml preamble; a BOM would be 0xEFBBBF as the first 3 bytes of the file - you want `settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;`