# System.Xml.XmlException: 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.' <-- even though ive changed the encoding and parts of xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I want to extract some data values from an XML that I have made but I keep getting an error

> System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

I thought it was the encoding so I tried changing it to UTF-32 or ASCII but its the same. All paths are correct. I even removed the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

but same thing here is some parts of the code:

Creation of XML:

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Path.Combine(location, "config.xml"), new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("EXMLE");
    writer.WriteStartElement("setupData");
    writer.WriteElementString("IsOffline", isOffline.ToString().ToLower());
    writer.WriteElementString("Username", username);
    writer.WriteElementString("Password", accPass);
    writer.WriteElementString("LoginKey", key);
    writer.WriteElementString("KeyPass", encKey);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    if (!isOnline)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("niniteOptions");
        writer.WriteElementString("ApplicationLine", applicationLine);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("OSDownload");
        writer.WriteElementString("CurrentVersion", currentVersion);
        writer.WriteElementString("CurrentRelease", currentRelease);
        writer.WriteElementString("CurrentLanguage", currentLanguage);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("OSConfig");
        writer.WriteElementString("OSUsername", osUsername);
        writer.WriteElementString("OSPassword", osPassword);
        writer.WriteElementString("DiskNumber", diskNumber);
        writer.WriteElementString("IsUsingDomain", isUsingDomain.ToString().ToLower());
        writer.WriteElementString("DomainLine", domainLine);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();

    MessageBox.Show("File made!");
}
```

and the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EXMLE>
  <setupData>
    <IsOnline>false</IsOnline>
    <Username>Alice</Username>
    <Password>*SENSITIVE DATA*</Password>
    <LoginKey> *SENSITIVE DATA*</LoginKey>
    <KeyPass>*SENSITIVE DATA*</KeyPass>
  </setupData>
  <niniteOptions>
    <ApplicationLine>'AIMP' + 'foobar2000' </ApplicationLine>
  </niniteOptions>
  <OSDownload>
    <CurrentVersion>10</CurrentVersion>
    <CurrentRelease>10, version 22H2 [19045.3803] (Updated December 2023)</CurrentRelease>
    <CurrentLanguage>English</CurrentLanguage>
  </OSDownload>
  <OSConfig>
    <OSUsername>Alice</OSUsername>
    <OSPassword>*SENSITIVE DATA*</OSPassword>
    <DiskNumber>2</DiskNumber>
    <IsUsingDomain>true</IsUsingDomain>
    <DomainLine>netdom.exe join MainHub /domain:enterprise.net /UserD:Alice /PasswordD:*SENSITIVE DATA*</DomainLine>
  </OSConfig>
</EXMLE>
```

and the problem code:

```
 private void getText()
 {
     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.Load(xmlLoc); -- where I get the error
     XmlNode dataNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/EXMLE/setupData");
     if (dataNode.SelectSingleNode("IsOnline").InnerText.ToLower() == "true")
     {
         isOnline = true;
     }
     else
     {
         isOnline = false;
     }
     serverUsername = dataNode.SelectSingleNode("Username").InnerText;
     serverPasswordEnc = dataNode.SelectSingleNode("Password").InnerText;
     serverKeyEnc = dataNode.SelectSingleNode("LoginKey").InnerText;
     serverKeyPassEnc = dataNode.SelectSingleNode("KeyPass").InnerText;

 }
```

I was hoping to get my data from XML.

Comment: What is `xmlLoc`?

Comment: Your XML file is well-formed according to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/.  Are you sure that your `xmlLoc` file name correctly refers to the file you wrote?  Is there any chance that `xmLoc` is the XML content itself rather than the file name?

Comment: This is a bad gotcha! with `XmlWriterSettings`; the default encoding is UTF8 with BOM. You need to use [`new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false), Indent = true }`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755958/).

Comment: xmlLoc is just the XML file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any whitespaces at the beginning of the file?  Try Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement setupData = doc.Descendants("setupData").FirstOrDefault(); 
            string serverUsername = (string)setupData.Element("Username");
            string serverPasswordEnc = (string)setupData.Element("Password");
            string serverKeyEnc = (string)setupData.Element("LoginKey");
            string serverKeyPassEnc = (string)setupData.Element("KeyPass");

        }
    }
}
```